# Проблема в создание приложения TODO в андроид студио

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Я создаю приложению по этому видео https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=guHJbPYKHUU&t=637s. Всё праильно, ошибок нету, но когда я запускаю приложение у меня задания создаются внизу[image]

Я уже пробывал на разных телефонах запускал, но всё равно ничего не меняется.
Вот мой проект https://drive.google.com/open?id=15edsjefA07cGvQ0YXH2USClVSrIhD2rZ
Прошу помогите, я уже 2 недели мучаюсь над этим.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не стал смотреть видеоурок, но у вас в row.xml главный RelativeLayout имеет размеры match_parent, а объекты внутри имеют привязки ко всем сторонам родителя. Высоту главного элемента 100% надо ставить wrap_content, а привзяки убрать лишние. Для текста отсавить привязку к левому краю, для кнопки - к правому. Хотя решение все равно такое себе, т.к. если текст будет достаточно большой, он уйдет под кнопку

Comment: извините может быть за глупый вопрос, а какой это главный элемент?

Comment: В row.xml у вас только один realtiveLayout, вот про него и говорю)

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное вы мне очень помогли, спасибо!!!